# How to access to remote server

Tags: apache, mercurial, ssh, webserver

I want to create a repository on the remote server .

Access constraint that I have :

(a) IP address (of server)
(b) username/pw

I am following [this tutorial](http://dev.lshift.net/paul/mercurial-server/docbook.html) and stuck in the first step :"Initial access to mercurial-server"

I am not able to understand those "ssh connection" syntax (specially the my-key)

How could I connect to remote server(using ssh-agent ) i order to create new repo .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same problem we see again and again. `mercurial-server` isn't a part of Mercurial.  It's a separate, third party, not generally necessary piece of software that tries to make mercurial administration easier without really succeeding.

Start here: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories/

and pick the type of access you want, http or ssh and then use either hgweb.cgi + apache (for http) or **nothing at all** if you just want to use ssh.

Specifically, for any server that has the mercurial client on it (`apt-get install mercurial` on debian or ubuntu and `yum install mercurial` on redhat, fedora, or centos) you don't need any extra software at all for hosting mercurial repositories over ssh.  You can just do:

```
hg clone myLocalrepo ssh://you@thatserver/myRemoteRepo
```

and **poof** you're hosting there.

Comment: thanks a lot , But I want to create new repo on the remote server by taking project files from http.myproject.com/path/to/project.zip . Does the "last" command will work for that .

Comment: Please could you be more generous and answer [to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668065/how-to-create-new-repo-of-existing-projectmercurial) as well .